# How to create stress testing for Azure mobile app?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services, backend

I create Azure mobile app for sync data from devices. I created this backend  on ApiController(post, get, delete, put requests). My app use azure sql database and cosmos db. 
  How to create stress testing for my Azure mobile app? 
  I found this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/load-test/app-service-web-app-performance-test). but it looks too general and simply. I want to check my controllers and databases under load. Is this possible?
  I do not have an UI in my backend, the client app sends data to my controllers. How can I do it in test?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that article you found is generalized. To load test your application, you need to create a `Web Performance and Load Test Project` in Visual Studio. This project allows you to define the calls you want to make to your controller(s) but more importantly the number of users to simulate and how to distribute your various tests. Unfortunately, this project type is only available with Visual Studio Enterprise (the top shelf).

To do this, simply create a new `Web Performance and Load Test Project` and add a new load test to it. With your application using a web API, you don't have a web UI to record the interactions between your application and the server. You will have to manually create your web requests. Simply right click on your load test and select "Add request"

[image]

Then you can right click on the request and go to "Properties". Here you can specify the URL and the HTTP method. You can also right click on the request and a body to the request in the case when you need to send data to the server.

There are other tools out there that will allow you to load test your application, but I'm not aware of any that integrate into Azure like the Microsoft tools do.

I suggest reading these articles as well:

[Load test your app in the cloud using Visual Studio and VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/load-test/getting-started-with-performance-testing)

[Tutorial: Load test your app before release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/load-test/run-performance-tests-app-before-release)

Comment: I read it, but I have many questions. I do not have an UI, the client app sends data to my controllers. How can I do it?

Comment: I've added some additional details to better explain how. Understand that you don't need a UI, you just need to know what requests your application will send to the server. With you not having a web UI, you need to manually create the web requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use App Service Continuous Deployment as mentioned [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/performance-testing-with-app-service-continuous-deployment/), to test performance every time you deploy bits.

You can use [VSTS Load Test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/load-test/get-started-simple-cloud-load-test) and [Visual Studio Load Test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/load-test/getting-started-with-performance-testing).